# A parallelogram is cut into four smaller parallelograms by two segments, one parallel to each pair of opposite sides.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A parallelogram is cut into four smaller
parallelograms by two segments, one parallel to each
pair of opposite sides. Three
of the small parallelograms have areas of 6, 8, and
12. Find all possibilities for the area of the original
(large) parallelogram.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. What's been tried, and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
$$
{4! \over 4 \cdot2}=?
$$
$$
A=12+8+6+a=?
$$
$$
 \left[ \begin{array}{}
6 & 8 \\
12 & a \end{array} \right] \to a=?
$$

> $a=16, A=42$

$$
 \left[ \begin{array}{}
8 & 6 \\
12 & a \end{array} \right] \to a=?
$$

> $a=9/2, A=30.5$

$$
 \left[ \begin{array}{}
12 & 8 \\
6 & a \end{array} \right] \to a=?
$$

> $a=4, A=30$